# how to move from localhost to server? Nodejs

Tags: node.js, deployment, server

I have a nodejs application working on my laptop. I can view it in the browser by going to `http://localhost:3030/`.

I have installed nodejs,npm and all the packages I need on a server and copied all the files on the server as well.

When I start the application using `node app` it seems to be running fine. But It can not find any of the public static content, client-side javascript, client-side css etc. I see 404 errors in my browser console.

All nodejs tutorials seems to stop at localhost.. how to deploy an app on a server?

Comment: It's Linux? can be read permission of the directory on the server

Comment: Which Webserver are you using?

Comment: You're missing a lot of info, you should post your code in question to better illustrate the issue. From the current question, there isn't enough to give any meaningful answer. Are you using Express, Sails, Kao, etc..? What environment are you attempting to host your app (Windows/Linux)?

Comment: Lucas your hunch was correct. It was a permissions issue.